# Why is entire website not downloaded?

Tags: wget, recursive

I tried to make a copy of the site `wiredhealthresources.net` using the command:

```
wget -rpkl inf wiredhealthresources.net
```

But the command only downloaded 54 files! Most of the pages are missing, e.g. `/topics-cardiology.html`, despite being linked to from `/index.html`

What did I do wrong? Why is `wget` not downloading the whole site?

Comment: While I can't answer the question itself, I would suggest giving [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/1/en/index.html) a try, as I have had more success with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the page source you won't see any `topics-cardiology.html` link because the sidebar is being generated by JavaScript.  You will need to use a JavaScript headless browser like [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) to make a complete mirror.

Comment: Ahh! Makes sense. I should have checked the source. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know of a good CasperJS script to mirror a website? I'm struggling to find one.

Answer (score -1):

I'm reasonably sure you can't use the `inf` option to modify depth, only to modify tries, or query. Have you tried using `-m` instead of `-r` and `-l`? It sounds like you want to mirror the page, and that's what `-m` is used for.

Comment: Both using `-l 99` and `wget -pkm` yield the same result: only 54 files downloaded. The man page says `-m` is equivalent to `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing`, which is where I got the `-l inf` from.